# Why are Sir Handel and Peter Sam identical to Falcon and Stuart?

Tags: thomas-the-tank-engine

Why are Sir Handel and Peter Sam of the Skarloey Railway completely identical to Falcon and Stuart of the closed-down Mid-Sodor Railway? They are the same types of engines, they both know Duke, and they know of the story about Stanley/Smudger/No.2 (the engine who was turned into a generator/pumping engine), and in the TVS, Sir Handel is Falcon’s blue and Peter Sam is Stuart’s green.

Comment: I've no idea why this is attracting downvotes. It's a pretty perceptive spot and well worthy of a question. That being said, there may be some doubt about whether TtTE is sufficiently fantastical to be on the site.

Comment: Well, this IS a franchise starring talking railway engines, rolling stock, and other vehicles.

Comment: Yes, but their existence in the stories isn't fantastical, it's merely part of the landscape of this world, and the trains are basically train-shaped-people.

Comment: Well, there are tales of ghost engines, everything about Thomas and the Magic Railroad, if you wanna check out more fantastical elements.

Comment: I believe the ghost engine was [revealed to be not real](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3450/20774), and the Magic Railroad is a [non-canon spinoff](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9877/20774). I'm still not seeing anything in the original stories that makes this topical.

Comment: But even if it’s not real it’s kinda…mystical…for the fireflies in Duncan Gets Spooked to make the shape of an engine…

Comment: [Is Thomas the Tank Engine on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13668/is-thomas-the-tank-engine-on-topic) - Scope questions are better asked+answered on Meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Rev. W. Awdry's *[The Island Of Sodor: Its History, People and Railways](https://ttte.fandom.com/wiki/The_Island_of_Sodor:_Its_People,_History_and_Railways)* the train known as Falcon *is* [Sir Handel](https://ttte.fandom.com/wiki/Sir_Handel) and Peter Sam *is* Stuart. They were purchased, repainted and renamed.

> **Falcon  and  Stuart  (formerly  Nos.  3 &4  of the  Mid  Sodor
> Railway, see DLE/14,15,56) were bought and renamed Sir Handel and
> Peter  Sam  respectively  (4LE/18,19).**  As revenue  further increased,
> Skarloey  and  Rheneas  were  rebuilt,  the  line  was gradually
> relaid (LOE/26,32), another locomotive, Duncan, was acquired (LOE/24),
> and rolling stock rebuilt and added to.
>
> <sub><sup>*The Island Of Sodor: Its History, People and Railways* - p. 48</sup></sub>